# How can I avoid inviting a whole party of mercenaries when attacking a fort?

Tags: assassins-creed-odyssey

When attacking a larger fort, the bounty on my head accumulates very, very quickly. And this happens fast enough that I usually get some mercenaries arriving right at the height of the battle.

On lower levels this wasn't that much of an issue, I did usually manage to kill the mercenaries as well. But I'm stuck a bit at a particular fort right now because the combined soldiers and mercenaries are a bit much for me.

How can I avoid having to fight multiple mercenaries at the same time as my actual targets when attacking a large fort?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Don't be seen while killing people

Simply put, your bounty increases every time you kill someone and someone else is there to witness it. Killing the witness is pointless, because your bounty has already been increased.

If you're playing a Fighter, make sure you only fight enemies individually. Alternatively, you can fight groups of enemies, but you should avoid dealing the killing blow. Once the group is weakened enough, hide somewhere, and then pick them off without being seen by others.

If you're playing a Hunter, make sure nobody can see where you are, even if they witness the kill.

---

In addition to being sneaky, sabotaging the brazier should be one of your higher priorities. When lit, your bounty increases substantially.

Comment: That's probably a good idea, but quite unlike my current playstyle of charging directly into the horde of enemies. I discovered that the major reason it was much harder than before in this case was that the fort was covered by the olympic truce, and a combination of particularly annoying mercenary types.

Answer (score 17):

Find the alarm brazier in the fort. When you get close to it you are prompted to 'set trap'. Once the trap is set anyone trying to light the alarm causes an explosion and the brazier is disabled. With no alarms the mercenaries don't turn up (unless you already have a bounty).